# POST 405 (Method not allowed) when trying to post AJAX request - Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to issue a simple AJAX request to populate a menu in Laravel, however, I am having a lot of trouble with getting it to work properly.

I am not sure what the issue is, and after a couple hours of searching, I cannot find anything that can help.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/populateApiAuth',
            data: json,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (json) {
                alert('test');
                return true;
            },
            error: alert('fail')
});
```

My route to the AJAX callback:

```
Route::get('/ajax/populateApiAuth', 'ApiController@populateApiAuth');
```

and my controller to handle the AJAX callback in ApiController:

```
public function populateApiAuth()
    {
        return Response::json(array('msg' => 'test');
    }
```

When sending the AJAX request, it returns with the fail message in the error parameters, and in the console, it tells me:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/ajax/populateApiAuth 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Researching this error message, it results from making a POST request to a different domain/server? How can this be?

I have tried to use an absolute URL for the AJAX request with:

```
url: '{{ URL::to("ajax/populateApiAuth") }}
```

which gives the full URL: `http://localhost:8000/ajax/populateApiAuth` but that does not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Wouldn't this be your issue?

```
Route::get('/ajax/populateApiAuth', 'ApiController@populateApiAuth');
```

You set the route up for GET requests, but you're trying to access it via a POST request.

Comment: I quite literally just realized that as I hit submit... Feeling really stupid now, and yes that solved my issue. FACEPALM

Comment: @user3771990 It happens. Sometimes, writing it out can allow you to see something that you overlooked before :)

Comment: I will accept your answer when it lets me, and let this be an example for future Laravelers that fall into the same dumb mistake! :)