# Convert the ajax call for Datatable from Get to Post in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, datatable

I have tried to convert the below `datatable` javascript from `GET` to `POST` method. The code looks as below,

```
var pagination = new DatatablesPagination({
    tableSelector: '.casesTable',
    tableContainer: data.tableContainer,
    onError: callbacks.onError,
    iDisplayLength: recordsPerPage,
    pages: 4,
    sAjaxSource: ajaxSource,
    fnServerParams: function(aoData) {
        $.each(additionalQueryParams, function(index, additionalQueryParam) {
            aoData.push(additionalQueryParam);
        });
    },
    fnDrawCallback: function(settings) {
        if (typeof callbacks !== "undefined" && typeof callbacks.onDrawOfAssociatedCases !== "undefined") {
            callbacks.onDrawOfAssociatedCases(settings, reportHolder);
            if ($("#associatedCasesTableWrapper").is(":visible")) {
                updateLocation();
            }
        }
    }
}):
```

I have tried adding sServerMethod: `POST` as below, but there is no luck.

```
   sServerMethod: 'POST',
        sAjaxSource : ajaxSource,
        fnServerParams : function ( aoData ) {
            $.each(additionalQueryParams, function(index, additionalQueryParam) {
                aoData.push( additionalQueryParam );
            });
        },
```

Could anyone help me to convert this method from `GET` to `POST` please?

Comment: what is the `console` error your are getting in `network`?

Comment: 405 method not allowed in status code

Answer (score 0):

Might be your Service/Server setup would be configured with `GET`, but your are trying to access it with `POST` from ajax. Try changing the service setup to `POST`.

Please refer,

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21287/ajax-load-results-in-networkerror-405-method-not-allowed

[POST 405 (Method not allowed) when trying to post AJAX request - Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312766/post-405-method-not-allowed-when-trying-to-post-ajax-request-laravel-4)