# The POST method is not supported for this route even though i am using get method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

my route is

```
Route::get('functionvalueupdate',[\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,'functionvalueupdate'])->name('functionvalueupdate');
```

in script

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{route('functionvalueupdate')}}",
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        success: function(res) {

        }
    }
)
```

controller

```
 public function functionvalueupdate(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

Console log error

```
allfunctionalarea:1 POST http://localhost/FESROZGAR/allfunctionalarea 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

still i get this error **The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**

Comment: check if there is another route defined with the same uri, and try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: still no luck :( I am literally fed up with what sort of error or stupid mistake I am doing...

Comment: first check route `php artisan route:list` your route exist or not. if not then run `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: it does exist :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is not right here.

Your route, show that GET to `functionvalueupdate` .

However, your console log show at different route. Which is

`http://localhost/FESROZGAR/allfunctionalarea` . I didn't see any route to `functionvalueupdate`.

Or something like `http://localhost/FESROZGAR/functionvalueupdate` .

Please double check your POST or GET to the correct route. You can inspect element to see if the `{{ route('functionvalueupdate') }}` print the right route.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this for make the debuging better

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{route('functionvalueupdate')}}",
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error:function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
)
```

And please add the console.log error in your question and add your controller to the your question too

Comment: tried still no luck and the parameter (res) i know it has no use right now but the problem is with post method

Answer (score 0):

Change get to post in route as given below:

```
 Route::post('functionvalueupdate'[\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,
'functionvalupdate'])->name('functionvalueupdate');
```

Also change ajax type from get to post and don't forget to include csrf token in ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{route('functionvalueupdate')}}",
        data: {
            id: id,
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        error:function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: still no luck, this error has never happened before I don't know what I am missing

Comment: Please refer to this link you are facing the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312766/post-405-method-not-allowed-when-trying-to-post-ajax-request-laravel-4/25312796

Comment: but i am using the correct method :( i have get  method in  both methods

Comment: pass your id with route name and remove request from controller function just dd($id);